# Why minify is not enabled by default in gradle build process

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, minify

Why minify is not enabled by default in the `gradle` file of android?

Why proguard doesn't come with strictest rule by default in `gradle` file in android?

```
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Answer (score 1):

For debugging you want `minifyEnabled false`.  Otherwise you won't be able to debug through your code while you are testing.  That is why they have it false by default.

It should only be true for release version.